# ASP.NET Web API, 405 status code and exception handling

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes, http-status-code-405

Is there a way to catch a 405 on Web API and return a custom message when the wrong Verb is sent?  I am catching 500's by using ExceptionFilterAttribute.  I am wanting to return a JSON or XML object.

Comment: Could you give example how the wrong Verb sent, ex: you api does not support POST when client still send POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed is your friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx

Check Request.StatusCode for it in your filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the web.config using the customErrors element inside the System.Web.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url" mode="On">
   <error statusCode="statuscode" redirect="url"/>
</customErrors>
```